# Five accounts seem to be lost, gone. Where have they disappeared? 

Tags: support, user-accounts

Logged on to Pro Webmasters and found that I have not made a account for it yet. I said to myself I says, that I have already made a account on it so I just continued and then I got an "Oops! Something bad happened error."

I then clicked the home button and found that I had to start from scratch again. I went on Server Fault and the same thing happened.

On Meta.SO I clicked on my accounts tab and saw that I lost about five accounts. At the moment I have 19 but I did have over 20.

Where have they gone?

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of your recent questions or answers, on one of the accounts you lost?

Comment: @Robert for Server Fault and Webmasters?

Comment: Yes, on one of the accounts you lost when you got the error.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/what-are-some-good-apache-settings-to-use-with-wordpress/9193#9193 for Webmasters and on Server Fault all my posts have been deleted.

Comment: OK, your account on Webmasters looks OK, but it says in your post that you're 12 years old.  Did you know that you have to be age 13 or above to participate on the SE network?

Comment: @Robert no sorry

Comment: Bah. Solution: Change your birthdate to show you're 13 until you really *are* 13 :)

Comment: Yeah, so it looks like what happened is your account on ServerFault may have been deleted by a moderator.  You can email Team@StackOverflow.com for clarification.  Include this information in your email: http://serverfault.com/users/45831/benny

Comment: @Pekka - nice way to demonstrate that the impressionable mind of a child isn't safe here :)

Comment: @Hans hahahaha! Next up: How to create a fake ID for buying beer.

Comment: @Benny: Wait wait wait, is this your birthday? Looked at your Meta profile, and you're 13 now.

Comment: [COPPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act).

Comment: @Dan: pfffft how typical american!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/legal

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Stack Exchange may offer to provide the Services, as described more fully on the Network, and which are selected by Subscriber, solely for Subscriber’s own use, and not for the use or benefit of any third party. Services shall include, but not be limited to, any services Stack Exchange performs for Subscriber, as well as the offering of any Content (as defined below) on the Network. Stack Exchange may change, suspend or discontinue the Services at any time, including the availability of any feature, database, or Content.
>
> ...
>
> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that if Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity), Subscriber is at least 13 years of age. No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address)

We're removing your unused accounts, and placing all the other accounts in suspension until you reach age 13.

Comment: Erhm... and, sorry?

Comment: Sorry, but to me, this reads like "You didn't read our terms and conditions, so we have the moral right to suspend you without advance warning or any kind of accompanying  'sorry, we have to do this'. If you ask about it, we will shove a quote from said T&C into your face.". Is this a proper way to treat devoted users? Is it so hard to at least notify them in advance - seeing as they've not really done anything wrong, at least not by any reasonable standard?

Comment: @Pekka I don't think Jeff has a choice here.

Comment: @badp he can't notify them in advance? I'm having a *very* hard time believing that.

Comment: @Pekka Dunno, Nyu did say he received a mod message from Marc with his suspension.

Comment: @badp But @Benny apparently didn't. Plus is it that difficult to add a nice word or two, maybe that this has legal reasons, and that they're welcome back when they're thirteen?

Comment: I wonder what's so illegal about using a Q&A site when you're younger than 13 years old. This is pathetic!

Comment: @fretje - the issue as I see it is not the participation, it's the collection of personal information from not just a minor, but a pre-teen. This is just asking for trouble. I'm sure they can still participate in the site, but in an anonymous manner. Read the terms and conditions carefully - it only applies to subscribers (i.e. accounts) and the providing of personally identifiable information. Nothing about participation.

Comment: @Farseeker: Yeah, yeah, I know... it's just the fact that there is überhaupt a rule about this (that COPPA thing) that I find pathetic.

Comment: @fretje - to be honest, I would be upset if I knew that my pre-teen son was providing personal info on the net, be it facebook or stack overflow (actually that's a lie; I'd be impressed as he's only 10 months old), so I support the terms and conditions on this one simply from a parental standpoint.

Comment: @pekka - I agree with your sentiments here @jeff - what happened to "be nice", this post just sounds like yet another blunt and officious proclamation from the Oberst-Gruppenführer. You're beginning to sound more cranky than I am :) http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/46137062717538304