# Suspension reason listed as "to cool down" if "something else" reason is selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, account-suspension, moderator-messages

When choosing a message template for a moderator message, we are given several default choices, such as excessive promotion, abusive activity, etc. For cases which don't fit this bill, we have a "something else..." option.

For some reason, when suspending a user under this template, their profile will show "This account is temporarily suspended to cool down", instead of showing no reason, which would make more sense.

This goes against [the purpose of including a reason in the suspension banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-account), which is to reduce speculation and discussion in the community of "oh gosh, why was *user-x* suspended??". When the "something else..." template is chosen, the reason should be left empty (as the behavior used to be) or there should be a wide range of alternative choices. Otherwise, you end up with users who [were suspended for being under 13](https://superuser.com/users/75658/jmeyer10) (which is a TOS violation) but their profile says they need to cool down for *3 years*.

Comment: I would be in favor of "for rule violations."  It doesn't have to be more specific than that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey would "For TOS violations" perhaps be more specific and correct in this case? I think generally speaking, there will always be edge cases, so we should have an option to just not specify a reason.

Comment: Not stating a reason would defeat the whole purpose.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-account

Comment: @RobertHarvey but stating the wrong reason is counterproductive to the purpose.

Comment: "For rule violations" almost certainly covers any reason you might want to suspend someone for "something else;" it's specific enough to avoid the Streisand Effect, but vague enough to preserve the suspended user's privacy.

Comment: Fair enough @RobertHarvey. As I mentioned in the edit to my question, it would be good to have some more options. That would cover the situation though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No -- the entire purpose of this is to *avoid* having moderators enter something there, something potentially problematic.

We can change it to something other than "to cool down" but manual entry is a non-starter.

edit: I changed it to

> for rule violations

which, I am not entirely convinced is any better or more meaningful than "too cool down", but... be careful what you ask for, I guess. :p

Comment: I edited my question to clarify - I'm not saying we should necessarily have manual entry, I'm saying we should have something other than "to cool down", because "to cool down" is often _not_ the reason.

Comment: Seems more truthful at least. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Animuson said on chat that mods can now enter custom reasons.